# Get list of all user with attributes from AD with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, active-directory

I'm having trouble with some VBA programming since I'm totally new to it.
I've been given the task to create a macro/vba application in Word/excel that retrieves Lastname, Firstname | telephone number | Department | Manager from the Active Directory.
So I've been searching the internet for the last days but nothing really works for me.
A Template that gets the current Users First-/Lastname, email etc. was given to work on. I am having a hard time on transferring the code to what i need to do now.
So what I've been trying for the past hours now, was getting a list of all the Users from the Active Directory. But the Code I use was from a VBScript I found on the internet. I changed what I could to make it work with VBA but I always get an error when trying to run it.
The code is the following:

```
    Sub test()
' get OU
'

strOU = "OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"

' connect to active directory
'

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;"

' create command
'

Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000

' execute command to get all users
'

objCommand.commandtext = "LDAP://" & strOU & ">;" & _
  "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person));" & _
  "adspath,distinguishedname,sAMAccountName;subtree"

On Error Resume Next
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Exception occured: " & Err.Description
On Error GoTo 0

'Dim RecordSet As New ADODB.RecordSet
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

'Show info for each user in OU
'

Do Until objRecordSet.EOF

  'Show required info for a user
  '

  Debug.Print obj.RecordSet.Fields(“adspath”).Value
  Debug.Print obj.RecordSet.Fields(“distinguishedname”).Value
  Debug.Print obj.RecordSet.Fields(“sAMAccountName”).Value

  ' Move to the next user
  '

  obj.RecordSet.MoveNext

Loop

' Clean up
'

obj.RecordSet.Close

Set obj.RecordSet = Nothing
Set objCommand = Nothing

objConnection.Close
Set objConnection = Nothing

End Sub
```

and in this line it all stops everytime:

```
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
```

if I remove the `If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Exception occured: " & Err.Description
On Error GoTo 0` part it just freezes and crashes word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,  let's go top down:

```
strOU = "OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

With this nobody can help you. You must know the AD structure of your AD. If this is wrong, then you get "Table not found" from LDAP.

```
objCommand.commandtext = "LDAP://" & strOU & ">;" & _
  "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person));" & _
  "adspath,distinguishedname,sAMAccountName;subtree"
```

This lacks a `<`. It should be:

```
objCommand.commandtext = "<LDAP://" & strOU & ">;" & _
  "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person));" & _
  "adspath,distinguishedname,sAMAccountName;subtree"
```

Then

```
  Debug.Print obj.RecordSet.Fields(“adspath”).Value
  Debug.Print obj.RecordSet.Fields(“distinguishedname”).Value
  Debug.Print obj.RecordSet.Fields(“sAMAccountName”).Value
```

Multiple problems here:

1. Typographically double quotes are not allowed as string delimiter in VBA source code.
2. Your Object is named `objRecordset` and not `obj.Recordset`.

So this should be:

```
  Debug.Print objRecordset.Fields("adspath").Value
  Debug.Print objRecordset.Fields("distinguishedname").Value
  Debug.Print objRecordset.Fields("sAMAccountName").Value
```

Replace `obj.Recordset` with `objRecordset` also in the rest of the code.

Comment: i've done that now, thank you. but now i get an error with the first line: "variable "StrOU" not defined" and before it always stopped at the "Do Until objRecordSet.EOF" part cause the objRecordSet seems to be empty.
Maybe there are some references missing?
Right now I have some standard references and Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 2.8 Library, Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library, Active DS Type Library (in that order).

Comment: found some mistakes/typos in the strOU line. it seems to work now! but it just goes through the users without printing them out in word. what am i missing?

Comment: I was missing that everything was shown in the Editor that i had to open with Ctrl + G. Everything works now! Thanks again for the Help Axel!